# Does a Sublime Text plugin exist that makes creating Ruby classes and methods faster?

Tags: ruby, sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

Is there a Sublime Text plugin for Ruby that, after I type `class/def something` + <kbd>Enter</kbd>, will automatically insert `end` and place the curser in the class/method?

For example, typing `def initialize(args)` + <kbd>Enter</kbd> would result in:

```
def initialize(args)
  #cursor here
end
```

Comment: you should look at snippets: http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/snippets.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Textmate if you type `def` + <kbd>Tab</kbd>, it sets things up for you like that. I believe Sublime does the same.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used sublime, but here is what i found.

1. you could create snippets using Ruby on [Rails Snippet](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/Ruby%20on%20Rails%20snippets) package
2. You could use the solution given in '[How to automatically add "end" to code blocks?](http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=8302)'.